# using stored procedure in code first

Tags: stored-procedures, ef-code-first

I have a code first model with 2 table :

```
public class Company
{
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public string CompanyName { get; set; }
    public string CompanyAddress { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<User> User { get; set; }
}

public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public virtual int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

I want select Company with User Object with Stored Procedure

```
SELECT  a.*,u.* FROM  [dbo].[Companies]  as a
        INNER JOIN dbo.Users u on u.CompanyId=a.CompanyId

 CompanyDB c = new CompanyDB();
 var cc = c.Database.SqlQuery<Company>("dbo.Company_Select")
```

My problem : cc.User is Null   ???

Answer (score 0):

First, you have virtual in the wrong place for User:

```
public class User
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public int CompanyId { get; set; }
    public virtual Company Company { get; set; }
}
```

Second, why the stored procedure? When properly configured you can do:

```
var companiesWithUsers = db.Companys.Include(c => c.User).ToList();
```

Comment: because i need extra field with one select . expamle : i need select 10 rows from Comapny and select all rows count to paging

Comment: Lots of Linq to Entities options for shaping and filtering. For example,  db.Companys.Include(c => c.User).Skip((page -1) * PageSize)                       .Take(10).ToList();